# Why are my text boxes repeating in SSRS?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

This is the very first report I'm doing so.. Be gentle. My report in design mode looks like so:

[image]

Got an image there in the top right, some text boxes below that, and then a nice table. However when I run the report...

[image]

I immediately start hyperventilating. My table looks perfect, people will cry. But look at those text boxes, why are they also repeated? I haven't even linked up any fields to them?

Comment: Do you have them grouped as details? The rows you don't want repeated I mean.

Comment: I actually have no idea what you're talking about (awkward) . How do I do what you're talking about?

Comment: The row field (in grey) will have 3 horizontal lines against it to show it is classed as details.

Comment: The rows that you don't want repeated, are they in the same Tablix as the rows that you do want repeated, or are they in a separate Tablix?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cut out just the two textboxes and paste them into the top of the report or (anywhere not in the detail area). 
You will be left with a repeating detail area on top of your report.

Delete it and move the saved textboxes to where you want it.

To really save time just delete the entire area (which includes the boxes around the two text boxes that are repeating, and then just insert text boxes, add text and format.